# How to store sql files in json format for python

Tags: python, sql, json, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use `aws-lambda`function to hit a database and extract some data, and drop it into an `s3-bucket`
I have multiple `.sql` files that I want to store the queries from the `.sql` files in a json file and make the database in python from the json files.

.sql file query:

```
SELECT item_id,
       ite_invoice_id as invoice_id,
       ite_sku as SKU,
       ite_description as description,
       ite_qty_shipped as quantity,
       ite_unit_price as unit_price,
       ite_extension as extension,
       ite_pick_uom as unit_of_measure
FROM item
```

and then store it in a json file like this:

```
    barney_queries = {
      "acqut": "path/to/query_folder.item_sql"
    }
for key, sql_query in aquisitions.barney_queries():
  post_connection.cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

I'm not entirely sure if I got the structure down correctly.